# saving/writing time to txt file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to save the time into the existing txt file so that I can know when this particular record is added..I have this code to auto detect the time

```
time_t Now1;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char time1[20];
time(&Now1);
timeinfo = localtime(&Now1);
strftime(time1, 20, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", timeinfo);
Passports.Record_Added_On = time1;
cout << "\n\nRecord Added On: " << Passports.Record_Added_On;
```

code of reading the txt file:

```
fs = new fstream(Passports_FILE_NAME, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
            if (!fs)
            {
                cout << "\n Can't open or create '" << Passports_FILE_NAME << "' file" << "\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
            recs_num = -1;
            while (fs->read((char *)&Passports, sizeof(Passports)))
            {
                recs_num++;
                if (Passports.ID == id && !Passports.Deleted)
                break;
            }
            if (fs->eof()) //if (the record is not in the file || it's there but it's Deleted)
            {
                cout << "\nThe specific passports record does not exists in the file.";
                closeFile(fs);
                cout << "\n\nExit\n";
                return 0;
            }
```

it worked fine even when I display..however when I closed the program and open it again..
it shows weird characters like this or sometimes crashes..can anyone help me on this and explain what is the reason behind it?

[image]

Comment: In `C++`, consider using `std::chrono`. I'm also not exactly sure how to read your question, please be more clear.

Comment: How do you write to a file? From your code posted, you write to stdout

Comment: @mic_e i'm trying to save the time i get into a txt file so that when i search this record it will be displayed..but what i get is the weird characters in the picture

Comment: Try null-terminating `time1`.

Comment: @user3442192: You're not even showing the code that reads the textfile, how are we supposed to find the bug in it?

Comment: @0x499602D2 if i used null terminating will my space between %Y and %H get removed?

Comment: Why would it be removed? What I meant was to do `char time1[20] = {0}` or `time1[20] = '\0'`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 tried char `time1[20] = {0};` but still give me weird characters meanwhile the program will crash if i used `time1[20] = '\0'` before the `Passports.Record_Added_On = time1;` is there any possibility that it is caused by the 20? because the actual characters in the format is 16 with spaces

Comment: Can you show Passports structure declaration?

Comment: @Bogolt do you mean how i declare the txt file? this? `#define Passports_FILE_NAME "Passports.txt"
Passports_Record Passports;`

Comment: I mean this this code:
    while (fs->read((char *)&Passports, sizeof(Passports)))

i wounder how Passports structure or class defined, so to check if any error can happen after you read it from file to memory.

Comment: @Bogolt i suppose is this? 
`fs = new fstream(Passports_FILE_NAME, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
if (!fs)
{cout << "\n Can't open or create '" << Passports_FILE_NAME << "' file" << "\n";
system("pause");
}
    fs->write((char *)&Passports, sizeof(Passports));
closeFile(fs);
cout << "\n\nRecord Added.\n";
    `

Comment: hm, variable Passports. Where it is declared? What type is it? If it's of custom type, can you show it's declaration. Something like struct Passports{ int ID; ... };

Comment: @Bogolt `struct Passports_Record //Passports record
{int ID;
string Name;
string IC_No;
int Age;
string Gender;
string Date_Of_Birth;
string Place_Of_Birth;
string Nationality;
int Duration;
string Date_Of_Issue;
string Date_Of_Expiry;
int Fee;
string Record_Added_On;
string Record_Added_By;
string Record_Last_Updated_On;
string Record_Last_Updated_By;
string Remarks;
bool Deleted;
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize non POD objects ( like std::string class ) from memory. This leads to crashes because class does not know it is initialized. There is no guarantee that all class members where properly initialized from this code. Suppose that there was some class member which was pointer to some memory, allocated for you data. You saved it to file, then run your application again to load it. Then the pointer gets the same numeric value, but there is no more memory which he was pointing at. The memory must be allocated by OS, after OS function call, which was not called in our case. So next time you try to use this badly initialized class object - it crashed because it tries to work with memory which does not belongs to your application.
 To fix this crash you should parse the file contents properly and then fill your Passports record accordingly.
For example:

```
int int_value;
std::string string_value;
fs >> int_value >> string_value;
```

after that you can initialize your object:

```
Passports.ID = int_value;
Passports.Name = string_value;
```

etc. The same way you should use to save data to the file ( this is called serialization, i recommend you search more on the topic ).

Comment: Is the special characters above considered as crash? This is part of my assignment and our lecturer has given us the prototype of the program such as the new fstream and all. The question is if i changed the code will it affect my whole program? As of now, the program worked fine for everything except when calling back the date data in the txt file

Comment: No special characters are ok. Crash is when you app stops working suddenly. But nevertheless this is completely wrong to read non POD class from file like you did. Even if it's not crashing - this is error prone method of doing things.
Does your lecturer asked you to read/write to file only with this way?

Comment: When I added a null terminator such as `time1[20] = '\0'` before `Passports.Record_Added_On = time1;` it crashes. Well all the read/write function are given as the prototype of the project

Comment: As the size of your time1 variable is 20 then time1[20] is behind the array borders, so that's why it crashes. Try time1[19] = 0;

Comment: So any idea how to fix the special characters?

Comment: You should stop reading/writing object from it's memory, and use safer methods instead. Write: fs << Passport.ID << endl << Passport.Name << ...
Read: 
fs >> Passport.ID >> Passport.Name >> ...
Then check variable by variable where problem starts.

Comment: Is there anyway to get it to work without messing with the existing fstream? I know I am asking too much but I am not sure how strict he is on this and I do not want my marks to get deducted for changing the prototype of the program

Comment: can you post exact program prototype you have?

Comment: somehow I can get it to work with the format of %d/%m/%Y or %H:%M either one. If i try to combine it together all the weird characters is back. Any idea how to solve this?